# Mixing CDI and EJB results in error at start

Tags: ejb, cdi, weld, payara-micro

we have mixed the usage of CDI and EJB in our application. At startup, we receive the error `Caused by: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`.

We don't understand where exactly the problem is, so here is just the overall structure of the code:

```
@Stateless
public class SomeFacade {
    @Inject
    private SomeService someService;
}

@Stateless
public class SomeService {
    @Inject
    private SomeDao someDao;
}

@Stateless
public class SomeDao {
    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {
   @Produces
   @ApplicationScoped
   public EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory() {
         EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("one");
     return emf;
   }

   public void close(@Disposes EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
       entityManagerFactory.close();
   }

   @Produces
   public EntityManager createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
      return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
   }
}
```

Is there something we can change in general?

Comment: Can you pinpoint where is the exception coming from? E.g. which injection or bean call. From your code there is no visible place where you would be using `RequestScoped`. And EJB's `Stateless` are, accordingly to spec, viewed as `Dependent` by CDI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ondrej, your answer was helpful but was not quite the solution in my case.

First, I somehow resolved the start-up issues, but received the same error when handling arriving messages / REST requests. The solution was to annotate the service class with `@ActivateRequestContext`. This enabled CDI injections in all classes that are used by the servive.

Answer (score 2):

The error is raised because your code tries to access a request-scoped CDI bean in a moment when there's no request scope. Request scope is only created for incoming requests (HTTP requests via Servlet or JAX-RS, JMS MDBs, asynchronous EJB calls, etc.).

If you get this error during startup, I guess you access a request-scoped bean before CDI is fully started, e.g. from a singleton EJB. Try moving your code into a CDI that starts on start-up after CDI is initialized with:

```
@Dependent
public class CDIStartupBean {
    public void startup(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object event) {
        // Start-up code here. The CDIStartupBean can inject request-scoped beans
    }
}
```